# Importing multiple ASCII text files in ArcGIS as Rasters

Tags: raster, arcmap, ascii

I have a big number of ASCII text files which have the Esri ASCII Grid format but have been stored as .txt files rather than asc. I am trying to import them simultaneously as rasters to obtain mean values from the various files.

I have already tried to create a mosaic dataset and import the files as Rasters but I get a 999999 error (potentially because my files have a different extension? that is txt instead of asc.)

Please see below a sample of my dataset - that is one of the many ASCII text files that I need to import as raster

[image: Sample of my dataset - that is one of the many ASCII text files that I need to import as raster]

Comment: I doubt the file suffix has a bearing. Have you tried using as-is? Have you tried renaming?

Comment: I tried using as is and renamed the file but it still does not work with the mosaic dataset (import files as Rasters)

Comment: So it's the file, not the naming. It's nearly impossible to tell from the question, but it seems that the EOL encoding is <CR> not <LF> or <CR><LF>

Comment: The header information each need to be on a different line.  From you example it looks like they are on the same line. http://resources.esri.com/help/9.3/arcgisdesktop/com/gp_toolref/spatial_analyst_tools/esri_ascii_raster_format.htm

Comment: @Vince is there anything I can do about it?

Comment: @GBG I tried saving the header information in the same format but still get the error.

Comment: Can you make one of the files available?

Comment: Not sure if I "can" upload any of these files as the datasets are not public. Thanks for your suggestions, I managed to work around with this through R.